# Why method fail when called from uibutton but not from a gesture?

Tags: ios, methods

I'm new to ios programming and I'm stuck with an error. My app is for a magazine and I use a UIScrollView to see the articles.

In my app I have 2 ways to navigate in a UIScrollView, using a Gesture and with 2 buttons, because I change the content of the scrollview depending on page and use a method to go forward and one to go backwards, inside them I use a If to evaluate if it was the first page or the last page and disable the buttons depending on the case.

The first time i access the view with this methods everything is fine but on a second access the buttons fail but the gesture works fine, is there a difference when calling a method from a button or a gesture?

Here is the code:

```
//Here is where I assign the method to the buttons and gesture
[articuloAnterior addTarget:self action:@selector(cambiarPaginaAnterior) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[articuloSiguiente addTarget:self action:@selector(cambiarPaginaSiguiente) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *avanzarPagina = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cambiarPaginaSiguiente)];
avanzarPagina.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *regresaPagina = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cambiarPaginaAnterior)];
regresaPagina.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

//Here are the functions
-(void)cambiarPaginaAnterior{
//This method checks if it is the first page, in case it isn't it go one page back
NSLog(@"Pagina actual %d de %d",paginaMostrada,[appDelegate.seccionActual.listadoArticulos count]-1);
if (0 != paginaActual) {
    paginaMostrada = paginaActual - 1;
    NSLog(@"Pagina actual %d de %d",paginaMostrada,[appDelegate.seccionActual.listadoArticulos count]-1);
    [self cambiarLimites];
  }
}

-(void)cambiarPaginaSiguiente{
//In this method I check the actual page (paginaActual) to see if it is the last one, if it isn't then it go forward
NSInteger limiteDePaginacion = [appDelegate.seccionActual.listadoArticulos count] - 1;
 NSLog(@"Pagina actual %d de %d",paginaMostrada,limiteDePaginacion);
if (limiteDePaginacion != paginaActual) {
    paginaMostrada = paginaActual + 1;
    NSLog(@"Pagina actual %d de %d",paginaMostrada,limiteDePaginacion);
    [self cambiarLimites];
  }
}

-(void)cambiarLimites{
//Here i save the point where the user was located and save it in an array
NSValue *posicionActualDeLaVista = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(0, contenedorGeneral.contentOffset.y)];
[posicionDeLaPagina removeObjectAtIndex:paginaActual];
[posicionDeLaPagina insertObject:posicionActualDeLaVista atIndex:paginaActual];

//Here I change the value of the actual page
paginaActual=paginaMostrada;

//Here I disable the buttons or make them able
if (paginaActual==([appDelegate.seccionActual.listadoArticulos count]-1)) {
    articuloSiguiente.enabled = NO;
}
else {
    articuloSiguiente.enabled = YES;
}
if (paginaActual==0) {
    articuloAnterior.enabled = NO;
}
else {
    articuloAnterior.enabled = YES;
}

//A log to check the state of the buttons
NSLog(@"Pagina actual %d estado del boton anterior %@, estado del boton siguiente %@",paginaActual,articuloAnterior.enabled?@"yes":@"no",articuloSiguiente.enabled?@"yes":@"no");

//Acces an array with the points the user where
CGPoint puntoDeVisualizacion = [[posicionDeLaPagina objectAtIndex:paginaActual]CGPointValue];

//Here I remove the content of the uiscrollview and put the new one
[vistaTemporale removeFromSuperview];
vistaTemporale = [vistasParaElScroll objectAtIndex:paginaActual];
vistaTemporale = [self ResizeDeLaVista:vistaTemporale laPagina:paginaActual];
[contenedorGeneral addSubview:vistaTemporale];
[contenedorGeneral setContentOffset:puntoDeVisualizacion animated:NO];

//Check the view height and change the UIScrollView content height
float limitanteDeAltura;
limitanteDeAltura = [[appDelegate.viewSizes objectAtIndex:paginaActual]floatValue];
[contenedorGeneral setContentSize:CGSizeMake(anchoDeVista, limitanteDeAltura)];
}
```

I made my own gesture because I need to negate the diagonal scrolling so I thought it was a good idea to only show one view at a time, but the gesture is not the one failing, the buttons are not getting disabled, they are declared in the .h file and in the first access they work fine, any idea why are they failing?

Comment: The way you've worded your question (ie. all in one long sentence) makes it difficult to understand, but if I'm right in thinking that you're using a UIGestureRecognizer and UIButtons to control the behavior of a UIScrollView, you're doing it wrong.  UIScrollView has gesture recognition built in, and you shouldn't override that.  I'm not saying there isn't a case where using buttons to scroll it wouldn't make sense, because maybe there is, but it sounds like you're overcomplicating things to me... Can you explain more clearly exactly what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but the problem was that I was adding the buttons in the toolbar and because a memory management error the buttons still where there, so the new buttons where disabled but the old ones where visible and active, sorry for the problem